# Gala constantly using 90%+ of CPU

Tags: gala, cpu

For some reason, Gala is constantly using at least 90% of my CPU when only a few programs are running. It slows the whole computer down, and it's a constant pain to do anything.

I'm using a GeForce 320M (MacBook Pro 7,1) with the latest proprietary drivers that I installed manually.

Could it be an xorg.conf problem? If so, what do I need to edit?

Thanks.